# No instance found for Prelude.Functor

Tags: purescript

I am following "Purescript by Example" book, and is implementing [the code in Chapter 5](https://github.com/paf31/purescript-book/blob/master/chapter5/src/Data/Picture.purs). But I get a compilation error that I don't understand.

I get compilation error on this line (the code compiles without this line):

```
showPicture = map showShape
```

The error is:

```
No instance found for Prelude.Functor _67
```

And the [error explanation](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/wiki/Error-Code-NoInstanceFound) does not make it clear for me. Why do I get this error?

I have these dependencies installed in my bower file:

```
"dependencies": {
  "purescript-console": "^0.1.0"
  "purescript-foldable-traversable": "~0.4.0",
  "purescript-globals": "~0.2.0",
  "purescript-math": "~0.2.0"
}
```

Comment: Did you give a type signature? The map function implies that you are using a Functor (in this case Array), but psc does not yet infer constraints, so you need a type signature to guide it.

Comment: @Phil: Thanks, that was the missing piece. If you add it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a type signature.

The `map` function implies that you are using a `Functor` (in this case `Array`). So the general type of your function is

```
showPicture :: forall f. (Functor f) => f Shape -> f String
```

You probably meant the more specific type

```
showPicture :: Picture -> Array String
```

However, `psc` does not yet infer constraints, so you need a type signature to guide it. Hopefully `psc` will infer constraints before the 1.0 release, but for now, this is the workaround.